# Generic user interface for editing C# application configuration files

Tags: c#, user-interface, configuration

I am developing some little tools in C#, basically they just work fine as a console application with some configuration values read from the exe configuration file (System.Configuration).

But editing an XML file is not what you could call a great User Experience, so I am searching for a tool/library that could create a simple configuration screen in WPF or Winforms for the user to change these values.

This should be possible to automate for many simple cases. I did not find any existing tools that could solve this problem. Does anyone know tools that create UIs for configuration files or any tools that could speed up the creation of such a tool?

It should not be a problem to create this in pure WPF, but any tool to speed up the process is welcome.

Comment: @close-voter: Why do you think this is off-topic?

Comment: You don't have to manually edit XML, there is ConfigurationManager which speeds it up 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

Comment: I know, thats not the point. I think my question was a bit ambiguous. I know how to edit the configurations programmatically, but: I am searching for an easy user interface for the end-user to edit some of those configuration values instead of having the end-user edit the XML file.

Comment: What did you end up doing? I have a console app but looking for a simple GUI to let the user set some basic configuration

Answer (score 3):

[ASphere](https://asphere.cz/en/index.html) is a freeware XML configuration editor.

Comment: Thanks Teodor, that project looks very good. But not what I am searching for. 
The tool should be used by the end-user to set a few values.

Comment: The download site (linked from the above blog entry) looks to be dead.